# Package mesa-filesystem backward compatibility

Tags: linux, centos7, rpm

The software that I am installing requires mesa-dri-filesytem:
This is the screenshot of the installer. I don't want to touch the file. like changing `mesa-dri-filesystem to mesa-filesystem`
[image: screenshot]!

but I am currently using Cento OS 7 which finds the package absolute:
[image: screenshot]

I am installing it to an offline server, so `yum install` won't work, I'm just getting the RPM then doing  `rpm -ivh [package-name]`

Please help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because you have already installed on your system package `mesa-filesystem-18.0.5` which obsolete (i.e. replace, supersede) the package `mesa-dri-filesystem` < 18.0.5. You are trying to install `mesa-dri-filesystem-11.0.7` and because 11.0.7 < 18.0.6 then rpm correctly refuse the action as `mesa-filesystem`.

But the `mesa-filesystem` at the same time provides `mesa-dri-filesystem`, e.g., on my system:

```
# rpm -q --provides mesa-filesystem
mesa-dri-filesystem = 19.0.8-1.fc30
mesa-filesystem = 19.0.8-1.fc30
```

So if your package requires `mesa-dri-filesystem` then your requiremens are fulfiled even when `mesa-filesystem` is installed.

Comment: great! Although I managed to just removed the package then installed the new version. Thanks for the --provides parameter. I'll use this next time.